# Should reused Visitors be static?

Tags: java, design-patterns, gwt, visitor-pattern

I'm writing a Canvas painting app.

For some operation I have a visitor that is to be used every time a drawing in selected by the mouse.
At the moment I recreate the visitor always again like:

```
Visitor visitor = isStateSelected ? new SelectionVisitor() : DrawVisitor();
```

Should I consider making these visitors static, or at least introduce a private field for them? Or could one argue that the present way is more clean and object creation is not a big overhead?

Comment: I would certainly argue the latter. Making them `static` or even persistent introduces thread-safety as an issue. Making code less readable more more bug-prone is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a State Pattern for triggering the appropriate Visitor. Caches are really a bad idea in the application layer. Domain model classes should not refer to them, they should exist only in the config layer.

Comment: Could you give some hints what you exactly mean be "state pattern triggering visitor"?

Comment: Sure. The State Pattern (page on Wikipedia) is one of the easier ones to use. Basically, you are going to literally change the reference you are using when the state changes, so let's say you have a context object that has a reference to the visitor. When the state changes, you simply reassign that reference. Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Answer (score 1):

If this object creation is a bottleneck for your app, I think a private cache would be the next step.  If it's not slowing you down, I think you can move on to the next problem.

I love attempts to keep code clean.  If you don't want to muddy your code with a cache of visitors, you can keep it separate by wrapping this in a `private getVisitor()` method of its own that manages the cache variables.